# How to import CDN css links to reactjs using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to import CDN css libs into my reactjs project using webpack.
I have succeeded CDN js libs using [scriptjs-loader](https://github.com/ded/script.js). Stackoverflow already answered for js libs, now i am seeking for css libs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use webpack to load CDN or external vendor javascript lib in js file, not in html file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250174/how-to-use-webpack-to-load-cdn-or-external-vendor-javascript-lib-in-js-file-not)

Comment: I have seen that, that is for js libs

Comment: Hello Ravi,
were you able to find an answer for this?

Comment: No. It would be nice if someone answers.