# How to load remote file in webpack

Tags: asynchronous, reactjs, webpack

```
 the remote file is a single components compiled by webpack 
  the wenpack config as follow:


    {
     .....
     library: library
    ,externals: externals
    ,libraryTarget: "umd"
     .....
    }
```

the components  is in the cdn,
i want to load and use the remote components in  react.
and how to use it like the Pseudo code :

```
   ajax -> get a json > { components name } > use the name to load romote file    
   for example the json have the botton i need to load the botton.min.js

    var Button = reuqire('http://botton.min.js')
    class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Botton/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use webpack to load CDN or external vendor javascript lib in js file, not in html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250174/how-to-use-webpack-to-load-cdn-or-external-vendor-javascript-lib-in-js-file-not)

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install scriptjs
var $script = require("scriptjs");
$script("//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js", function() {
  $('body').html('It works!')
});
```

Comment: first,thaks for your ask, i found a same idea as you, https://github.com/yariv/ReactScriptLoader

Comment: I'm giving this a +1 because one of the creators of Webpack had the same answer here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/240#issuecomment-40686135

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the other post: I have looked around for a solution and most of all proposals were based on externals, which is not valid in my case.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62603539/8650621

Basically, I finished using a separate JS file which is responsible for downloading the desired file into a local directory. Then WebPack scans this directory and bundles the downloaded files together with the application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find solutions on the following resoures:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33293033/1204375
- [how to use webpack to load CDN or external vendor javascript lib in js file, not in html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250174/how-to-use-webpack-to-load-cdn-or-external-vendor-javascript-lib-in-js-file-not)
- [Webpack and external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530254/webpack-and-external-libraries)
- [How to use a library from a CDN in a Webpack project in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575809/how-to-use-a-pre-built-webpack-bundle-from-cdn-in-a-webpack-project)
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/150
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/240