# Is there a better include or import CSS from CDN into a CRA app without ejecting

Tags: css, reactjs, import, sass

I have checked out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49048317/7015414) but just wondering if there is a better way of importing a CSS file into a react component just like any other JS file.

something like SCSS's `@import url('cdn-url.css')`
And without using webpack or react-script-loaders

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can link your cdn in index.html... if u want to use sass you need to follow oficial documentation(dont require eject)