# CDN vs Webpack for React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cdn, react-dom

So I'm attempting to create my first React application, and when I compile it using webpack, I get a pretty large JS file, because it includes all React, React-DOM, etc.

Is there any way I can use one of the many React CDN's out there and still use

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a library from a CDN in a Webpack project in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575809/how-to-use-a-library-from-a-cdn-in-a-webpack-project-in-production)

Comment: I think this would actually be efficient if most web apps were actually loading react and react-dom from the CDN, so the libraries world already be in your browser for your app to use, but the promoted way is create-react-app which bundles it all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at webpack externals feature: 
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

This was made for this use case.