# Webpack 4 Expose Libraries to window object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lodash

I'm trying to expose some libraries like lodash to be available to the outside world via window object,

I've tried the shimming way but doesn't work https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/

```
   plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       _: 'lodash',
     }),
   ],
```

And i also tried the expose loader https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader
but it doesn't seem to work in webpack 4.

**How to expose some libraries like lodash to be available to the outside world via window object ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should get the library from [cdn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31575848/1641941)?

Comment: it's a valid option but I like to keep it in a webpack standard way,
I'm trying to load javascript bundle into my main app so don't want to bundle the used packages again

Answer (score 1):

Why not just import the library inside your code, and then expose it? Is there any benefit to using Lodash as a plugin?

> npm i lodash

```
 import _ from 'lodash'
 window._ = _;
```

To be honest it seems Lodash even exposes this object to the global scope automatically(worked for me even without the last line)

Comment: thank you for your answer :) 
actually there is another way also by writing this line in the entry file 
```
import "expose-loader?_!lodash"
```
but I like to keep it the webpack standard way